# Runtime.HandlerNotFound Error in AWS Lambda Function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to test/run my Lambda function with the runtime : python3.8.

My .zip file has a test.py file which has the main function named as 'lambda_handler'.

In the Lambda console>Basic Settings> my handler is: test.lambda_handler (following the filename.functionName norm)

I have made sure that the test.py file exists in the .zip file.

After Testing this file, I receive the following error:

```
**{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'test'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound"
}**
```

Any ideas as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a **spelling mistake**.

Instead of

```
lamba_handler
```

you should have

```
lambda_handler
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I corrected that but the error still persists

Comment: @PranjalJain Have you updated the question. The error message still says ""Handler 'lamba_handler' missing on module 'test'"".

Comment: Yes I did update the question. As I mentioned, the error still persists